# Powershell: Look for a folder name using a variable that will have a different value and length every time

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have found answers all around this, but not *quite* what I am looking for. I'm not a programmer, so adjusting very complicated scripts has proven difficult.

Periodically we are provided a .zip file.  The filename (before the .zip extension) will be different most of the time. It could be letters or numbers, and vary in length.

I already have a PowerShell script that unzips the contents of the file into a folder named after the file (because the contents originally were in a folder with that name), using Windows' native unzip technology.  It then distributes the folder where it needs to go, then moves the folder to an "already deployed" folder, and then cleans up by deleting the .zip.  That all works great.

The problem is, sometimes the destination already contains a folder with the same name, so we want that backed up first.  I need PowerShell to see check or not there is a folder with that name, then copy it to a "rollback" folder.

I currently have a script that does all of this, but it uses an array (that I found) that assumes the filename always will contain 9 characters. I would like my script to just look at the foldername that was already created from the unzip process, rather than the filename.  Or, for the existing array to lop off the last four characters (.zip) instead of always utilizing the first nine.  Make sense?

Here is what I have right now:

```
# Following code sets variables

$filelocation = dir d:\admin\Type\files\*.zip
foreach ($file in $filelocation){
$filename = $file.name.ToString()
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace("d:\admin\Type\files\$filename")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace("d:\admin\Type\files\")

#Following line unzips the file

$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items()) 
}

# Following chunk of code (that I found) converts the .zip filename to a string variable we can use in our Test-Path to see whether the folder already exists.
# NOTE: Right now it uses only the first 9 characters, but I would like it to only use the basename of the above zip file
# Or we could have it look at the name of the folder that results from the unzip (which always will match the basename of the .zip file)

$Directory = "d:\admin\Type\files";
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory | where {$_.extension -eq ".zip"};
$FileNames = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach($File in $AllFiles) 
{
    $FileNames.Add($File.Name.SubString(0,9));  
}

# The above code loses me a bit, because it was written for someone whose filename will always be nine characters, and can handle multiple files.
# Ours rarely will be more than one file, and will vary in length.

# Following code says "if the folder exists in the website structure, back it up to the group.backups folder"

if(Test-Path -path "D:\acronym\CurrentVersion\website.acronym\Type\Brands\$Name")
{
Copy-Item D:\acronym\CurrentVersion\website.acronym\Type\Brands\$Name D:\group.backups\Type\Brands\ -force -recurse
}   

# Following line removes the original .zip file from the files folder

Remove-Item d:\admin\Type\files\*.zip -force

# Following chunk of code copies the folder and its contents to the web server folder structure

Copy-Item d:\admin\Type\files\$Name D:\acronym\CurrentVersion\website.acronym\Type\Brands\ -force

# Following lines copy the folder and its contents to the completed folder
# and then removes the folder and its contents from the files folder (for some reason Move-Item was only moving the files)
# The files folder alway should be completely empty after this script finishes

Copy-Item d:\admin\Type\files\* D:\admin\Type\completed\ -force -recurse

Remove-Item d:\admin\Type\files\* -force -recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a specific answer (not enough details provided), but Powershell has some very good built-in Help.
If you run these commands and read the help provided you should at least have enough information to get you started.

```
 Get-Help Test-Path -Full
 Get-Help Move-Item -Full
```

Comment: My first time asking a question, so I'm not sure what details are missing.  Do I need to post the actual script I'm using? I would have to edit it quite heavily because of corporate security concerns, but I could do that.  The Test-Path and Move-Item commands, I'm already using.  What I need is a way to grab the filename characters before the .zip extension, or the foldername (which will differ in length every time) and see if it's already present in the destination folder. I have done the rest.  Thanks.

Comment: You can post a sample of what you've got, and examples of the folder structures you're dealing with.  You can get the filename (without the extension) by the .basename property.